# Substring in php through value retrieve from database

Tags: php

I am trying t0 perform a substring on DATETIME, the value of DATETIME is retrieve from database through mysql.

Example:

DATETIME: 2013-07-31 12:30:60
Year: 2013
Month: 07
Day: 31
hour: 12
minute: 30

My below code does not work.
How should I go about doing it?

```
 <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM auctionItem;";
        // Write a statement to open a connection to MySQL server
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "gfg");
        // Write a statement to select the required database
        mysql_select_db("KXCLUSIVE", $link);
        // Write a statement to send the SQL statement to the MySQL server for execution and retrieve the resultset
        $resultset = mysql_query($sql);
        // Write a statement to close the connection
        mysql_close($link);

    $dateTime = $row["startTime"];
    $year = substr($dateTime, 0,4);
    $month = substr($dateTime, 5,7);
    $day = substr($dateTime, 8,10);
    $hour = substr($dateTime, 11,13);
    $minute = substr($dateTime, 14,16);
    echo "year " .$year."<br></br>";
    echo "month " .$month."<br></br>";
    echo "day " .$day."<br></br>";
    echo "hour " .$hour."<br></br>";
    echo "minute " .$minute."<br></br>";
    ?>
```

Comment: What column type is `$row["startTime"]` stored as? MySQL has date functions too.

Comment: if you are using PHP >= 5.2.. thei best way to do this is by using datetime::format.. check this out http://us3.php.net/datetime.format

Comment: @Dinesh Datetime exists as of PHP 5.3 not 5.2

Comment: @bwoebi .. actually i said greater than equal to (>=) as mentioned on the docs: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @Dinesh Oh, I confused `format` with `createFormFormat`. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

`substr` wants as third parameter a length, not a position where to stop.

Correct would be:

```
$year = substr($dateTime, 0,4);
$month = substr($dateTime, 5,2);
$day = substr($dateTime, 8,2);
$hour = substr($dateTime, 11,2);
$minute = substr($dateTime, 14,2);
```

Comment: was just about to respond with this .. second value in substr is a length, not a position

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) class for this:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2013-07-31 12:30:60');
echo "year " .$dt->format('Y')."<br></br>";
echo "month " .$dt->format('m')."<br></br>";
echo "day " .$dt->format('d')."<br></br>";
echo "hour " .$dt->format('H')."<br></br>";
echo "minute " .$dt->format('i')."<br></br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code have a missing part:

```
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM auctionItem;";
        // Write a statement to open a connection to MySQL server
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "gfg");
        // Write a statement to select the required database
        mysql_select_db("KXCLUSIVE", $link);
        // Write a statement to send the SQL statement to the MySQL server for execution and retrieve the resultset
        $resultset = mysql_query($sql);
        // Write a statement to close the connection
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset); //this was lost
        mysql_close($link);

    $dateTime = $row["startTime"];
    $year = substr($dateTime, 0,4);
    $month = substr($dateTime, 5,7);
    $day = substr($dateTime, 8,10);
    $hour = substr($dateTime, 11,13);
    $minute = substr($dateTime, 14,16);
    echo "year " .$year."<br></br>";
    echo "month " .$month."<br></br>";
    echo "day " .$day."<br></br>";
    echo "hour " .$hour."<br></br>";
    echo "minute " .$minute."<br></br>";
?>
```

PS: Dont use mysql extension....go for mysqli or PDO instead

Answer (score 0):

Using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$time = '2013-07-31 12:30:60';
$timestamp = strtotime($time);

$year = date('Y', $timestamp);
$month = date('m', $timestamp);
$day = date('d', $timestamp);
$hour = date('H', $timestamp);
$minute = date('i', $timestamp);
$second = date('s', $timestamp);

echo $year.' '.$month.' '.$day.' '.$hour.' '.$minute.' '.$second.'<br>';
```

Using [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$time = '2013-07-31 12:30:60';
list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second) = preg_split('/-|:|\s/', $time);
echo $year.' '.$month.' '.$day.' '.$hour.' '.$minute.' '.$second;
```